# PHP image resizing option

Tags: php, html, css, function

I have this code to show the featured images of my wordpress posts on mailchimp RSS Campaigns and it works but it shows the image on its original size, I was wondering if you could help me with the code in order to resize all images to a same size.

```
function featuredtoRSS($content) {
  global $post;
     if ( has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) )
     {
        $content = '' . get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'full', array( 'style' => 'float:left; margin:10px 15px px 0;' ) ) . '' . $content;
     }
     return $content;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a wordpress question, but here is the answer

YOu should make an your own image size and add it in wordpress functions.php

```
add_image_size( 'samesize', 500, 200, true );
```

You can read more about it [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size)

And then in your code you will call your image size instead of full (full means the full width and height copy of your image)

```
get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'samesize'
```

rest of your code :)

Comment: Hey Bojan, thank you very much. Somehow the problem got fixed, first I managed to solve it by adding a "max-hight" of 40% and it worked ok, but then I erased that property and it was still working ok so that's kinda weird. Anyways, I tried sending test mails and they all look good except for Gmail, take a look http://i61.tinypic.com/xd6m9z.png. It should look like this: http://i61.tinypic.com/25502uf.png. I do now know why Gmail is resizing it to that huge size. I would really appreciate some help, thank you very much.

Comment: It is because the image is taking the full height and the width is changed, so you need to add height: auto; to the image so it resizes depending on the image width :) And it is better to serve smaller images (with image size) instead of the full version, that way the images will load faster (smaller size) and you will have an uniform image size overall :)

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [post_thumbnail](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail) function ref. that's what you're looking for,

on most templates there are already some default sizes:

```
    the_post_thumbnail();                  // without parameter -> 'post-thumbnail'

    the_post_thumbnail( 'thumbnail' );       // Thumbnail (default 150px x 150px max)
    the_post_thumbnail( 'medium' );          // Medium resolution (default 300px x 300px max)
    the_post_thumbnail( 'large' );           // Large resolution (default 640px x 640px max)
    the_post_thumbnail( 'full' );            // Full resolution (original size uploaded)
```

plus with an array you can set

```
the_post_thumbnail( array(100, 100) );  // Other resolutions
```

This works inside the loop, to access the function from outside use the get_the_post_thumbnail()

to set new sizes use `add_image_size().`

Answer (score 0):

Your current styles are not going to resize your image. `float:left;` will push your image to the left, and margin will simply add spacing on each side of the image.

You are looking for `width: ;` and `height: ;`.